# bash - Function to escape character?

Tags: bash, shell-script, escape-characters

I am trying to automate some of my stuff and facing a issue, the problem boils down to escaping the value that is being passed as a argument to the script.

#### myScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

loadPatch -name $1
```

where `$1` is the first argument and can have value like 'p12.9.5-bug34'

Running it as

```
myScript p12.9.5-bug34
```

produces no result. I checked with `echo $?` the output was successful, but the required operation didn't happen.

I replaced `$1` with this actual value to test in the script and it worked as expected. There is no way for me to put a print statement in `loadPatch` to verify what arguments it has received.

So, I envisage there is some escaping problem here and hence need to know, is there any function/utility which I could use to escape the argument before using?

Please let me know if you see any other error with this?

Comment: `p12.9.5-bug34` is a completely harmless name and should work fine despite the lack of quoting `"$1"`.  Your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I suggest a quick `set -x` so you can see what's actually being executed.

Comment: You should [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting). Escaping leads to way more complicated code.

Comment: As @l0b0 indirectly suggests, do you get better results with `loadPatch -name "$1"`

Comment: Did you edit the script on a Windows machine? [Script failing with "command not found: ^M"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47280)

Comment: @l0b0 the quoting didn't solved the problem. I envisage it's some other problem, might be with the binary prog I am using... So, currently just going with a hard coded way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question asked, because others may search for this title:

- zsh only: `print -r -- ${(q)var} ${(qq)var} ${(qqq)var} ${(qqqq)var}`
  for different types of quoting.
- ksh93, zsh, or bash: `printf %q "$var"`
- BusyBox (and all above).

  Use of vars level out differences between ash, bash and ksh:

  ```sh
  q1="'"
  q2="'\''"
  printf '%s\n' "'${var//$q1/$q2}'"
  ```

  Not in dash and old shells (those missing ${var//pat/str}).
- most portable?

  ```sh
  printf "'%s'\n" "$(printf '%s' "$var" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g")"

  Or

  printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g; 1s/^/'/; \$s/$/'/"
  ```

Improvements gladly welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

I agree there should not be a problem with special characters in that filename.

I have found that sometimes scripts are not running in the folder I expected.  If you replace "loadPatch -name" with "echo" you can verify $1 is what you expect.  If it is what you expect then add these lines to see if the current directory is what you expect:

```
ls -l $1
pwd
```